# JSF 2.0 view file name extension other than xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, web.xml

How can I use view files with a different extension, other than XHTML, still map to the Faces Servlet in a JSF 2.0 application ?

I am migrating a JSF 1.2 app to 2.0, and I use file name extensions jspx. I dont want to change them to xhtml.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my web.xml as of now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="JSF2Sample" version="2.5"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-tags.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xcss</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is fixed.

The following code fixed it.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
   <param-value>*.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And I got it from http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2137307&tstart=90

Thanks Michael, for lending a hand.

Answer (score 3):

In your web.xml add this:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, Michael. See the web.xml I added to the original post as detail.